# Deleting element from ItemsControl by pressing button XAML C++/CX

Tags: xaml, windows-8, microsoft-metro, itemscontrol, c++-cx

I am trying to delete an element from the following ItemsControl without using Window.CommandBinding. Is there an easier way to do this?

XAML:

```
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyStringArray}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <StackPanel/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Button Content="Abcd"/>
                        <Button Content="-" Click="Button_Click_1"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
```

If there is not an easier way, how can it be done with Window.CommandBindings

Also, in this code, how can I make the width of the first button take the entire width of the screen minus the width of the second button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to remove an item in an itemscontrol using a button on the item template is using a command binding with the command parameter bound to the current item.  You then remove the current item from the backing collection.

To achieve the button spacing you're looking for, use a grid for layout.  Create two `GridColumns`.  Give the first one a width of `*` and the second one a width of `Auto`.  Assuming you have the spacing for your `ItemsControl` set correctly, this will achieve the spacing your looking for.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Button Grid.Column="0" Content="Abcd"/>
    <Button Grid.Column="1" Content="-" Command="{Binding YourCommand}" CommandParamter={Binding}/>
</Grid>
```

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.commandbinding.aspx) for a more complete commmand binding example and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12486659/relay-command-in-windows-8-windows-store-app) for a convenience class for command binding.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't really understand the CommandBinding. I did find another method. I am using the following line of code in the button click method: myString = static_cast<Windows::UI::Xaml::Controls::Button^>(sender)->DataContext->ToString(); it gives me the value the corresponding of the string in the vector so I can do a search and delete element(I don't have duplicates). I don't really understand what DataContext returns. I assumed it gives the value of the binding of the first parent that has a binding

Comment: That does approximately the same thing.  The sender is the `Button`, so the `DataContext` of the button is the same as what is in context for the `Button`.  From you stuff above, `<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyStringArray}">`, this binding is looking at the `DataContext` of the `ItemsControl` and then looking for `MyStringArray` in it.